# How do I speed up an R module in python?

Tags: r, performance, rpy2, optuna

I'm using optuna for hyperparameter-tuning and the detrended cross-correlation coefficient (rhodccc) as metric that should be optimized. Its an R module that I imported to Python using rpy2.

As I've got lots of data, the calculation of the DCCC takes quite some time. Is there a way how to speed up R modules?

```
    def objective(trial):
    
        model = DGAN(DGANConfig(
            max_sequence_len=8760,
            sample_len=2190,
            batch_size=1000,
            epochs=trial.suggest_int('epochs_parameters',1000,100,200),
        ))
    
        # Train model
        model.train_numpy(data)
    
        # Generate values
        synthetic_values = model.generate_numpy(13)
    
        rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
    
        y1_vector = ro.FloatVector(data_linear)
        y2_vector = ro.FloatVector(synthetic_values)
    
        rhodccc = SlidingWindows.rhodcca_SlidingWindows(y1_vector, y2_vector, w=113880, nu=1) 

        rhodccc_mean = base.mean(rhodccc[2])

        return rhodccc_mean

   study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')
   study.optimize(objective, n_trials=3, gc_after_trial=True)
```